# JQuery autosubmit

Tags: html, jquery, forms

I have a form with three input elements. I want to run my validate function when the last input element is not equal to null. Any ideas please. Here's the code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#number input").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('#number input').focus();     
    }
 });

})
```

Here's the HTML :

```
 <div id="number">
      <form action="" id="myform">
        <input placeholder="hr" maxlength="2" type="number" id="uHrs" pattern="[1-12]" autofocus></input>
        <input placeholder="min" maxlength="2" type="number" id="uMins" pattern="[0-59]"></input>
        <input placeholder="sec" maxlength="2" type="number" id="uSecs" pattern="[0=50]"></input>
        <button type="submit" id="subtime" value="submit" onclick="checkInput()">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Pls provide the HTML code too!

Comment: Just make your life easy and run the validation on form submit.

Comment: @Zze Yes good idea. What you can do is shift the whole validation system to the backend where the form will be submitted. You can disable the submit button until the last input is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try filter, also I use the input event so we can paste. We could even split a too long number and spread it to the next fields if we want to support pasting the complete set of values

Full solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3mbqw80h/

```
$(function() {
  const $inputs = $("#number input"),
    $form = $("#number");
  $inputs.on("input", function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      const $next = $(this).next('#number input');
      if ($next.length) $next.select().focus();
      if ($inputs.filter(function() {
          return this.value.trim() !== ""
        }).length === $inputs.length) {
        checkInput();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for the answers, very helpful

Comment: Please tell me, why is that when I try to run cinsole.log($form.value) it returns undefined ?

Comment: I want to $form to return a value that is made up of all the $inputs, separated by a white space. For example (22 22 22). Can I please have some help with this please

Comment: Hi again. I created a JSfiddle. Please if you can spare a few moments to help with code please. I want the code to run for example 10 mins.And during that 10 mins the code must store and update the user's score. My stuck point is that the page reloads every time and therefore does'nt save the score. Here's the fiddle, please take a look and share your thoughts. https://jsfiddle.net/viwe/18yhtuo6/2/

Comment: Yes okay thank you very very much. I just need to learn exactly what that is and how it works. But honestly I've been working on this project for a month now. I'm so frustrated and starving. I even sold my wheel barrow so that I can buy a bit of data and try and complete this. There's potential for a job interview if I can do this and other projects. So   I guess I'm asking if it's not too much trouble for you to just make the corrections for me (with comments) so that I can study it and hand it over ASAP. Then I'll go back and read docs and books and such. This is overdue

Comment: I realise that I might be pushing my luck. Please don't be offended, I'm just beyond desperate. I can do some graphics design for you in return

Comment: At least there will be a later time for me to get into trouble. And hopefully by the time that time comes I will be able to explain. Right now I'm on w3schools, reading about AJAX. As for the fiddle. I checked and double check, even included a link to JQuery but still I have no idea why the inputs are not showing up. They are there in the HTML but for some reason JSfiddle is not showing them. Also as you can see from the mark up, I've put the project up on Firebase but I was reluctant to link that here as because some people won't follow unknown links : https://tentimes-5cb71.web.app/?

Comment: I have created a working solution for you at https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3mbqw80h/

Comment: wow thank you so much. this works great. I have it running locally on VSCode and the score is working perfectly. One thing, I'm not sure if I did something wrong but the inputs don't go back to the first label label after check_inputs() is run. But looking at the code, I'm thinking that I need to add that behaviour. But still this wonderful, you've really help me out a lot, throughout this entire project. I only wish that I could return the favour some how. If I can please tell me, anytime. Bless you sir

Comment: Change `document.getElementById("number").reset();` to   `$("#number")[0].reset();
  uHrs.focus();`

Comment: I'm floored. That is such a cool solution. So you're not just selecting a DOM element, but specifying it as an array. So that you can get the first index (specifically). Wow, this is some inspirational stuff.Thank you so much. I've never really been keen on studying JQuery, but looking at these amazing things that you are able to do, and make it look effortless, it's a no brainer. That takes nothing away from you of course. You are no doubt a seasoned vet who has been a guardian angel to countless over many years. No bout a backbone of stackoverflow and I'm blessed to have crossed your path

Comment: It is a LITTLE different. The [0] is the DOM element. - we need that because jQuery does not have a reset method so we want the native element. The trick was the focus. You could have kept the document.getElementbyId("number").reset() but I do not like to mix DOM and jQuery. We normally use .eq(number) to address elements in a  jQuery collections

Comment: :-)  Hopefully I will understand a higher percentage of what's going on after a few more weeks/months of study

Comment: Yes of course. I'm new so I did'nt even know about that.Yes most gracisouly